# Windows Server 2022--IIS Cannot modify file shares

Tags: iis-10, windows-server-2022

With a clean installation of Windows Server Standard 2022 as a VM on RedHat8, the IIS does not permit the Administrator to make any changes to a web sites file sharing permissions. In fact, it isn't possible to start with the defaults, then simply "Share" them.
The workaround is to use File Explorer to locate the directory you wish to share, then modify from that point without an issue.

Comment: "the IIS does not permit the Administrator to make any changes to a web sites file sharing permissions" is by design. IIS or IIS Manager does not take care of such file sharing settings. That's exactly the responsibilities of Windows Explorer (or its equivalent PowerShell commands).

Answer (score 0):

Use the File Explorer to locate the web site directory under C:\inetpub\wwwroot\the_directory_to_share and change the permissions there.